# Python zip function using

Tags: python

```
list = ([1,2,3], [2,3,4], [5,6,7])
print([x[0] - sum(x) for x in zip(*list[1:])])
print([x[0]*2 - sum(x) for x in zip(*list)])
```

I thought it prints same result, but it wasn't.
What's the different between two sentence?

Comment: Don't call your list `list` because that shadows the built-in type.

Comment: Why do you think two different operations on two different subsets of data should produce the same result?

Answer (score 1):

```
list = ([1,2,3], [2,3,4], [5,6,7])  # You should avoid using keywords as variable names.
print([x[0] - sum(x) for x in zip(*list[1:])])  # iterating from the index 1
print([x[0]*2 - sum(x) for x in zip(*list)])   # iterating from index 0
```

If you execute the following commands, you'll see the difference between the outputs of them.

```
>>> [*zip(*list[1:])]
[(2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7)]
>>> [*zip(*list)]
[(1, 2, 5), (2, 3, 6), (3, 4, 7)]
```

Hence, 1st command iterates over a list with 2 elements. Whereas, 2nd command iterates over a list containing 3 elements.

Comment: sum(x)  for x in zip(*list[1:])  => [7,9,11]       sum(x) for x in zip(*list) => [8,11,14]       x[0]=[1,2,5],     Is it wrong?

Comment: No x[0] = [2,3,4] in first one and x[0] = [1,2,3] in second one.

Answer (score 0):

the difference is that in the first sentence you take 2nd and 3rd elements of the original list only while in the second sentence you take the whole list plus you multiply by 2.

'list' renamed to 'll'

`ll[1:]` returns `([2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7])`